# Scrape Kubernetes metadata labels using Prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter

I have added some labels to kubernetes namespace metadata, now I want to scrape namespace as well as those labels using prometheus, Actually I am trying to create a grafana dashboard and want to categorise namespaces based on labels. I tried using kubernetes_sd_configs, I am able to get namespace but unable to get labels of those namespaces. Does anyone know of any way to scrape labels along with namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case somebody is also looking for answer, we can use [kube-state-metrics](http://kubernetes.github.io/kube-state-metrics/)

It exposes kube_namespace_labels metric which has labels as well as namespace.